# How to get the selected node level in Google Treemap

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

There is a way to get the current data level of the selected node.

For example in this case: https://jsfiddle.net/yojtv1fq/

```
    ['Shakespeare', null, 0],
    ['Tragedies', 'Shakespeare', null],
    ['The Tragedy Of Othello', 'Tragedies', null],
    ['Othello', 'The Tragedy Of Othello', 274],
```

- Shakespeare is level 0
- Tragedies is level 1
- The Tragedy of Othello is level 2
- Othello is level 3

How can I get the level when I click on them?

Answer (score 0):

use the `'select'` event to know when the tree has been clicked / selected.

then count the number of times we find a parent for the selected value.

to find the parent row, use data table method --> `getFilteredRows`

e.g.

on select, get value of parent for the selected row.

```
  var title = data.getValue(selection[0].row, 1);
```

find parent row.

```
    rows = data.getFilteredRows([{
      column: 0,
      value: title
    }]);
```

get value of parent for that row.

```
    if (rows.length > 0) {
      title = data.getValue(rows[0], 1);
      level++;
    }
```

repeat find parent row until a parent is not found.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['treemap']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Shakespeare', null, 0],

    ['Comedies', 'Shakespeare', null],
    ['Tragedies', 'Shakespeare', null],
    ['Histories', 'Shakespeare', null],

    ['As You Like It', 'Comedies', null],
    ['Adam', 'As You Like It', 10],
    ['Amiens', 'As You Like It', 10],
    ['Audrey', 'As You Like It', 12],
    ['Celia', 'As You Like It', 108],
    ['Charles', 'As You Like It', 8],
    ['Corin', 'As You Like It', 24],
    ['Dennis', 'As You Like It', 2],
    ['Duke', 'As You Like It', 32],
    ['Frederick', 'As You Like It', 20],
    ['Hymen', 'As You Like It', 1],
    ['Jaques (lord)', 'As You Like It', 57],
    ['Jaques (son)', 'As You Like It', 2],
    ['Le Beau', 'As You Like It', 14],
    ['Oliver', 'As You Like It', 37],
    ['Orlando', 'As You Like It', 120],
    ['Phebe', 'As You Like It', 23],
    ['Rosalind', 'As You Like It', 201],
    ['Silvius', 'As You Like It', 24],
    ['Sir Oliver Martext', 'As You Like It', 3],
    ['Touchstone', 'As You Like It', 74],
    ['William', 'As You Like It', 11],

    ['Comedy Of Errors', 'Comedies', null],
    ['Adriana', 'Comedy Of Errors', 79],
    ['Aegeon', 'Comedy Of Errors', 17],
    ['Aemilia', 'Comedy Of Errors', 16],
    ['Angelo', 'Comedy Of Errors', 31],
    ['Antipholus of Ephesus', 'Comedy Of Errors', 76],
    ['Antipholus of Syracuse', 'Comedy Of Errors', 103],
    ['Balthazar', 'Comedy Of Errors', 5],
    ['Courtezan', 'Comedy Of Errors', 11],
    ['Dromio of Ephesus', 'Comedy Of Errors', 63],
    ['Dromio of Syracuse', 'Comedy Of Errors', 99],
    ['Luce', 'Comedy Of Errors', 7],
    ['Luciana', 'Comedy Of Errors', 43],
    ['Pinch', 'Comedy Of Errors', 6],
    ['Solinus', 'Comedy Of Errors', 22],

    ['Merchant Of Venice', 'Comedies', null],
    ['Antonio', 'Merchant Of Venice', 47],
    ['Balthasar', 'Merchant Of Venice', 1],
    ['Bassanio', 'Merchant Of Venice', 73],
    ['Duke (of Venice)', 'Merchant Of Venice', 18],
    ['Gratiano', 'Merchant Of Venice', 48],
    ['Jessica', 'Merchant Of Venice', 26],
    ['Launcelot Gobbo', 'Merchant Of Venice', 44],
    ['Leonardo', 'Merchant Of Venice', 2],
    ['Lorenzo', 'Merchant Of Venice', 47],
    ['Nerissa', 'Merchant Of Venice', 36],
    ['Old Gobbo', 'Merchant Of Venice', 19],
    ['Portia', 'Merchant Of Venice', 117],
    ['Prince of Arragon', 'Merchant Of Venice', 4],
    ['Prince of Morocco', 'Merchant Of Venice', 7],
    ['Salanio', 'Merchant Of Venice', 18],
    ['Salarino', 'Merchant Of Venice', 27],
    ['Salerio', 'Merchant Of Venice', 6],
    ['Shylock', 'Merchant Of Venice', 79],
    ['Stephano', 'Merchant Of Venice', 3],
    ['Tubal', 'Merchant Of Venice', 8],

    ['Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 'Comedies', null],
    ['Bottom', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 59],
    ['Cobweb', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 4],
    ['Demetrius', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 48],
    ['Egeus', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 7],
    ['Fairy', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 4],
    ['Flute', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 18],
    ['Helena', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 36],
    ['Hermia', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 48],
    ['Hippolyta', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 14],
    ['Lysander', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 50],
    ['Moth', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 2],
    ['Mustardseed', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 5],
    ['Oberon', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 29],
    ['Peaseblossom', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 4],
    ['Philostrate', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 6],
    ['Puck', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 33],
    ['Quince', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 40],
    ['Snout', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 9],
    ['Snug', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 4],
    ['Starveling', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 7],
    ['Theseus', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 48],
    ['Titania', 'Midsummer Night\'s Dream', 23],

    ['Taming Of The Shrew', 'Comedies', null],
    ['Baptista Minola', 'Taming Of The Shrew', 68],
    ['Bianca', 'Taming Of The Shrew', 29],
    ['Biondello', 'Taming Of The Shrew', 39],
    ['Christopher Sly', 'Taming Of The Shrew', 24],
    ['Curtis', 'Taming Of The Shrew', 20],
    ['Gremio', 'Taming Of The Shrew', 58],
    ['Grumio', 'Taming Of The Shrew', 63],
    ['Haberdasher', 'Taming Of The Shrew', 1],
    ['Hortensio', 'Taming Of The Shrew', 70],
    ['Joseph',  'Taming Of The Shrew', 1],
    ['Katherina', 'Taming Of The Shrew', 82],
    ['Lucentio',  'Taming Of The Shrew', 61],
    ['Nathaniel', 'Taming Of The Shrew', 4],
    ['Nicholas', 'Taming Of The Shrew', 1],
    ['Peter',  'Taming Of The Shrew', 2],
    ['Petruchio', 'Taming Of The Shrew', 158],
    ['Philip',  'Taming Of The Shrew', 1],
    ['Tranio', 'Taming Of The Shrew', 90],
    ['Vincentio', 'Taming Of The Shrew', 23],

    ['The Tempest', 'Comedies', null],
    ['Adrian', 'The Tempest', 9],
    ['Alonso', 'The Tempest', 40],
    ['Antonio, duke of Milan', 'The Tempest', 57],
    ['Ariel', 'The Tempest', 45],
    ['Caliban', 'The Tempest', 50],
    ['Ceres', 'The Tempest', 4],
    ['Ferdinand', 'The Tempest', 31],
    ['Francisco', 'The Tempest', 2],
    ['Gonzalo', 'The Tempest', 52],
    ['Iris', 'The Tempest', 4],
    ['Juno', 'The Tempest', 2],
    ['Master', 'The Tempest', 2],
    ['Miranda', 'The Tempest', 50],
    ['Nymphs', 'The Tempest', 0],
    ['Prospero', 'The Tempest', 114],
    ['Reapers', 'The Tempest', 0],
    ['Sebastian', 'The Tempest', 67],
    ['Stephano (Servant to Portia)', 'The Tempest', 60],
    ['Trinculo', 'The Tempest', 39],

    ['Henry VIII', 'Histories', null],
    ['Anne Bullen', 'Henry VIII', 18],
    ['Archbishop Cranmer', 'Henry VIII', 21],
    ['Bishop Lincoln', 'Henry VIII', 2],
    ['Brandon', 'Henry VIII', 6],
    ['Capucius', 'Henry VIII', 5],
    ['Cardinal Campeius', 'Henry VIII', 14],
    ['Cardinal Wolsey', 'Henry VIII', 79],
    ['Cromwell', 'Henry VIII', 21],
    ['Doctor Butts', 'Henry VIII', 4],
    ['Duke of Buckingham', 'Henry VIII', 26],
    ['Duke of Norfolk', 'Henry VIII', 48],
    ['Duke of Suffolk', 'Henry VIII', 30],
    ['Earl of Surrey', 'Henry VIII', 24],
    ['First Secretary to Wolsey', 'Henry VIII', 2],
    ['Gardiner', 'Henry VIII', 22],
    ['Garter', 'Henry VIII', 1],
    ['Griffith', 'Henry VIII', 13],
    ['King Henry VIII', 'Henry VIII', 81],
    ['Lord Abergavenny', 'Henry VIII', 5],
    ['Lord Chamberlain', 'Henry VIII', 38],
    ['Lord Chancellor', 'Henry VIII', 7],
    ['Lord Sands', 'Henry VIII', 17],
    ['Old Lady', 'Henry VIII', 14],
    ['Patience', 'Henry VIII', 3],
    ['Porter (door-keeper of the Council-chamber)', 'Henry VIII', 10],
    ['Queen Katharine', 'Henry VIII', 50],
    ['Sir Anthony Denny', 'Henry VIII', 3],
    ['Sir Henry Guildford', 'Henry VIII', 1],
    ['Sir Nicholas Vaux', 'Henry VIII', 1],
    ['Sir Thomas Lovell', 'Henry VIII', 21],
    ['Surveyor to the Duke of Buckingham', 'Henry VIII', 9],

    ['History Of King John', 'Histories', null],
    ['Arthur Duke of Bretagne', 'History Of King John', 23],
    ['Blanch', 'History Of King John', 9],
    ['Cardinal Pandulph', 'History Of King John', 23],
    ['Chatillon', 'History Of King John', 5],
    ['Constance', 'History Of King John', 36],
    ['Essex', 'History Of King John', 1],
    ['Faulconbridge', 'History Of King John', 4],
    ['Hubert de Burgh', 'History Of King John', 52],
    ['James Gurney', 'History Of King John', 1],
    ['King John', 'History Of King John', 95],
    ['King Phillip', 'History Of King John', 43],
    ['Lady Faulconbridge', 'History Of King John', 5],
    ['Lewis the Dauphin', 'History Of King John', 29],
    ['Lord Bigot', 'History Of King John', 6],
    ['Lymoges duke of Austria', 'History Of King John', 16],
    ['Melun', 'History Of King John', 3],
    ['Pembroke earl of Pembroke', 'History Of King John', 20],
    ['Peter of Pomfret', 'History Of King John', 1],
    ['Philip the Bastard', 'History Of King John', 89],
    ['Prince Henry', 'History Of King John', 8],
    ['Queen Elinor', 'History Of King John', 22],
    ['Salisbury earl of Salisbury', 'History Of King John', 36],

    ['Antony And Cleopatra', 'Tragedies', null],
    ['Agrippa', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 28],
    ['Alexas', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 15],
    ['Antony', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 202],
    ['Canidius', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 10],
    ['Captain', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 1],
    ['Charmian', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 63],
    ['Cleopatra', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 204],
    ['Demetrius (Friend to Antony)', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 2],
    ['Dercetas', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 5],
    ['Diomedes', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 7],
    ['Dolabella', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 23],
    ['Domitius Enobarus', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 113],
    ['Egyptian', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 2],
    ['Eros', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 27],
    ['Euphronius', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 5],
    ['Gallus', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 1],
    ['Iras', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 18],
    ['Lepidus', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 30],
    ['Mardian', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 7],
    ['Mecaenas', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 16],
    ['Menas', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 35],
    ['Menecrates', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 2],
    ['Octavia', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 13],
    ['Octavius', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 98],
    ['Philo', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 2],
    ['Pompey', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 41],
    ['Proculeius', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 10],
    ['Scarus', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 12],
    ['Seleucus', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 3],
    ['Silius', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 3],
    ['Taurus', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 1],
    ['Thyreus', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 12],
    ['Varrius', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 1],
    ['Ventidius', 'Antony And Cleopatra', 4],

    ['Coriolanus', 'Tragedies', null],
    ['Aedile', 'Coriolanus', 10],
    ['Cominius', 'Coriolanus', 67],
    ['Coriolanus (Caius Marcius Coriolanus)', 'Coriolanus', 189],
    ['Junius Brutus', 'Coriolanus', 91],
    ['Lieutenant',  'Coriolanus', 4],
    ['Menenius Agrippa',  'Coriolanus', 162],
    ['Patrician', 'Coriolanus', 3],
    ['Roman', 'Coriolanus', 10],
    ['Sicinius Velutus', 'Coriolanus', 117],
    ['Titus Lartius', 'Coriolanus', 23],
    ['Tullus Aufidius', 'Coriolanus', 45],
    ['Valeria', 'Coriolanus', 14],
    ['Virgilia', 'Coriolanus', 26],
    ['Volsce', 'Coriolanus', 9],
    ['Volumnia',  'Coriolanus', 57],
    ['Young Coriolanus', 'Coriolanus', 1],

    ['Cymbeline', 'Tragedies', null],
    ['Arviragus', 'Cymbeline', 46],
    ['Belarius', 'Cymbeline', 58],
    ['Caius Lucius', 'Cymbeline', 25],
    ['Cloten',  'Cymbeline', 77],
    ['Cornelius (physician)', 'Cymbeline', 13],
    ['Cymbeline, King of Britain', 'Cymbeline', 81],
    ['Guiderius', 'Cymbeline', 62],
    ['Helen',  'Cymbeline', 0],
    ['Iachimo', 'Cymbeline', 77],
    ['Imogen',  'Cymbeline', 118],
    ['Jupiter', 'Cymbeline', 1],
    ['Philario', 'Cymbeline', 14],
    ['Pisanio',  'Cymbeline', 58],
    ['Posthumus Leonatus', 'Cymbeline', 77],
    ['Queen',  'Cymbeline', 27],
    ['Roman Captain', 'Cymbeline', 4],
    ['Sicilius Leonatus', 'Cymbeline', 7],

    ['The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 'Tragedies', null],
    ['Bernardo', 'The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 19],
    ['Claudius, King of Denmark', 'The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 102],
    ['Cornelius', 'The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 1],
    ['Father\'s Ghost', 'The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 15],
    ['Fortinbras', 'The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 6],
    ['Francisco ', 'The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 8],
    ['Gertrude', 'The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 69],
    ['Guildenstern', 'The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 29],
    ['Hamlet', 'The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 358],
    ['Horatio', 'The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 109],
    ['Laertes', 'The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 62],
    ['Lucianus', 'The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 0],
    ['Marcellus', 'The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 37],
    ['Ophelia', 'The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 58],
    ['Osric', 'The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 25],
    ['Polonius', 'The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 86],
    ['Reynaldo', 'The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 13],
    ['Rosencrantz', 'The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 48],
    ['Voltemand', 'The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark', 1],

    ['Julius Caesar', 'Tragedies', null],
    ['Antony (Marcus Antonius)', 'Julius Caesar', 51],
    ['Artemidorus of Cnidos', 'Julius Caesar', 4],
    ['Brutus (Marcus Brutus)', 'Julius Caesar', 194],
    ['Caesar (Julius Caesar)', 'Julius Caesar', 42],
    ['Calpurnia', 'Julius Caesar', 6],
    ['Casca', 'Julius Caesar', 39],
    ['Cassius', 'Julius Caesar', 140],
    ['Cicero', 'Julius Caesar', 4],
    ['Cinna', 'Julius Caesar', 11],
    ['Cinna the Poet', 'Julius Caesar', 8],
    ['Claudius', 'Julius Caesar', 2],
    ['Clitus', 'Julius Caesar', 8],
    ['Dardanius', 'Julius Caesar', 3],
    ['Decius Brutus', 'Julius Caesar', 12],
    ['Flavius', 'Julius Caesar', 5],
    ['Lepidus (Marcus Antonius Lepidus)', 'Julius Caesar', 3],
    ['Ligarius', 'Julius Caesar', 5],
    ['Lucilius', 'Julius Caesar', 10],
    ['Lucius', 'Julius Caesar', 24],
    ['Marullus', 'Julius Caesar', 6],
    ['Messala', 'Julius Caesar', 20],
    ['Metellus Cimber', 'Julius Caesar', 5],
    ['Octavius (Octavius Caesar)', 'Julius Caesar', 19],
    ['Pindarus', 'Julius Caesar', 5],
    ['Popilius (Popilius Lena)', 'Julius Caesar', 2],
    ['Portia (wife of Brutus)', 'Julius Caesar', 16],
    ['Publius', 'Julius Caesar', 2],
    ['Strato', 'Julius Caesar', 4],
    ['Tintinius', 'Julius Caesar', 10],
    ['Trebonius', 'Julius Caesar', 4],
    ['Varro', 'Julius Caesar', 6],
    ['Volumnius', 'Julius Caesar', 3],
    ['Young Cato', 'Julius Caesar', 3],

    ['King Lear', 'Tragedies', null],
    ['Cordelia',  'King Lear', 31],
    ['Curan',  'King Lear', 4],
    ['Duke of Albany', 'King Lear', 58],
    ['Duke of Burgundy', 'King Lear', 5],
    ['Duke of Cornwall', 'King Lear', 53],
    ['Earl of Gloucester', 'King Lear', 118],
    ['Earl of Kent', 'King Lear', 127],
    ['Edgar',  'King Lear', 98],
    ['Edmund', 'King Lear', 79],
    ['Goneril', 'King Lear', 53],
    ['King of France', 'King Lear', 5],
    ['Lear', 'King Lear', 188],
    ['Oswald', 'King Lear', 38],
    ['Regan',  'King Lear', 73],

    ['The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 'Tragedies', null],
    ['Angus', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 4],
    ['Banquo', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 33],
    ['Caithness', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 3],
    ['Donalbain', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 3],
    ['Duncan', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 18],
    ['Fleance', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 2],
    ['Hecate', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 2],
    ['Lady Macbeth', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 59],
    ['Lady Macduff', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 19],
    ['Lennox', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 21],
    ['Macbeth', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 146],
    ['Macduff', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 59],
    ['Malcolm', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 40],
    ['Menteith', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 5],
    ['Porter', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 4],
    ['Ross', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 39],
    ['Seyton', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 5],
    ['Siward', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 11],
    ['Son (Macduff\'s son)', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 14],
    ['Young Siward', 'The Tragedy Of Macbeth', 4],

    ['The Tragedy Of Othello', 'Tragedies', null],
    ['Bianca (Mistress to Cassio)', 'The Tragedy Of Othello', 15],
    ['Brabantio', 'The Tragedy Of Othello', 30],
    ['Cassio', 'The Tragedy Of Othello', 110],
    ['Desdemona', 'The Tragedy Of Othello', 165],
    ['Duke of Venice', 'The Tragedy Of Othello', 25],
    ['Emilia', 'The Tragedy Of Othello', 103],
    ['Gratiano (Brother to Brabantio)', 'The Tragedy Of Othello', 20],
    ['Iago', 'The Tragedy Of Othello', 272],
    ['Lodovico', 'The Tragedy Of Othello', 33],
    ['Montano', 'The Tragedy Of Othello', 24],
    ['Othello', 'The Tragedy Of Othello', 274],
    ['Roderigo', 'The Tragedy Of Othello', 59],

    ['Romeo And Juliet', 'Tragedies', null],
    ['Abraham', 'Romeo And Juliet', 5],
    ['Balthasar (Servant to Romeo)', 'Romeo And Juliet', 12],
    ['Benvolio', 'Romeo And Juliet', 64],
    ['Capulet', 'Romeo And Juliet', 51],
    ['Friar John', 'Romeo And Juliet', 4],
    ['Friar Laurence', 'Romeo And Juliet', 55],
    ['Gregory', 'Romeo And Juliet', 15],
    ['Juliet', 'Romeo And Juliet', 118],
    ['Lady Capulet', 'Romeo And Juliet', 45],
    ['Lady Montague', 'Romeo And Juliet', 2],
    ['Mercutio', 'Romeo And Juliet', 62],
    ['Montague', 'Romeo And Juliet', 10],
    ['Paris', 'Romeo And Juliet', 23],
    ['Peter (Servant to Juliet\'s Nurse)', 'Romeo And Juliet', 13],
    ['Prince Escalus', 'Romeo And Juliet', 16],
    ['Romeo', 'Romeo And Juliet', 163],
    ['Sampson', 'Romeo And Juliet', 20],
    ['Tybalt', 'Romeo And Juliet', 17]
  ], true);

  var tree = new google.visualization.TreeMap(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  google.visualization.events.addListener(tree, 'select', function () {
    var selection = tree.getSelection();
    if (selection.length > 0) {
      var rows;
      var title = data.getValue(selection[0].row, 1);
      var level = 0;

      do {
        rows = data.getFilteredRows([{
          column: 0,
          value: title
        }]);
        if (rows.length > 0) {
          title = data.getValue(rows[0], 1);
          level++;
        }
      } while (rows.length > 0);

      console.log(level);
    }
  });

  tree.draw(data, {
    highlightOnMouseOver: true,
    maxDepth: 1,
    maxPostDepth: 2,
    minHighlightColor: '#8c6bb1',
    midHighlightColor: '#9ebcda',
    maxHighlightColor: '#edf8fb',
    minColor: '#009688',
    midColor: '#f7f7f7',
    maxColor: '#ee8100',
    headerHeight: 15,
    showScale: true,
    height: 500,
    useWeightedAverageForAggregation: true
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry I don't want this. Following this example https://jsfiddle.net/yojtv1fq/ I need the zoom level of the selection. What you are getting is the row number of data, not the zoom level.